# MariaDB syntax error 1064, check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to manipulate an existing database found here https://github.com/SchadLucas/xbmcTweaks/blob/master/music.sql

But for some reason MariaDB doesn't like the syntax although it seems to be right according documentation

```
Error
SQL query: Documentation


DROP VIEW IF EXISTS artistview
CREATE VIEW artistview AS
SELECT DISTINCT  
artist.idArtist AS idArtist,strArtist,strBorn,strFormed,artistinfo.strGenres,artistinfo.strMoods,artistinfo.strStyles,strInstruments,strBiography,strDied,strDisbanded,strYearsActive,artistinfo.strImage,strFanart 
FROM artist   
LEFT OUTER JOIN artistinfo ON    artist.idArtist = artistinfo.idArtist
JOIN album ON album.strArtists = artist.strArtist
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE VIEW artistview AS
SELECT DISTINCT  
artist.idArtist AS idArtist,strArt' at line 2
```

Version running is:

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server version: 5.5.37-MariaDB - Source distribution
- Protocol version: 10
- User: root@localhost
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

I'm no SQL expert and can't seem to find what is going wrong.
Any ideas?

Comment: SQL statements need to be terminated (end with) with a `;`

Comment: You can also use [`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-view/) and remove the `DROP` statement.