# mysql : delete where not in : what is the syntax?

Tags: mysql

this gives me an error

```
delete  FROM `emails` WHERE `id`  not in (Select id From poi Where date>Now())
```

What is the syntax to be used ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: are you sure ? date>Now() - means that date in the future

Comment: date is reserved keyword so try this : 
`delete  FROM \`emails\` WHERE \`id\`  not in (Select id From poi Where \`date\` > Now() )`

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using reserved keyword of `MySQL` that time you have to use **backticks sign (`)** like this:

```
DELETE
FROM `emails`
WHERE `id` NOT IN
    (SELECT id
     FROM poi
     WHERE `date` > Now())
```

Comment: This works on my local server, but not in my remote: remote says : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3

Any idea ?

Comment: @yarek in MariaDB i don't have any idea. and it should work if it mis ok on localserver

Comment: @yarek check this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989445/mariadb-syntax-error-1064-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your-mariadb-ser